# Solr: Master documents with x children - how to index

Tags: solr, lucene

There are "dossiers" that are being indexed in Solr.
Each dossier has x persons connected to it.

It should be possible to search for persons and to search for dossiers. When searching for a person, the dossier should also be returned.

I was wondering, what would be a good way to index this?

Do I need to split the index in a "DossierIndex" and a "PersonIndex"? Or just throw them together even though they don't really have common fields. (Dossier has status, etc; Persons have names, birthdays etc)

Comment: don't think about Solr as Database :)

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look into *BlockJoin* capabilities in **Solr**, with it help you could index "dossiers" with nested persons.

I recommend amazing article about it - http://blog.griddynamics.com/2013/09/solr-block-join-support.html

More info - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-BlockJoinQueryParsers